# Control LCD back light

Tags: c++, windows

I'd like to control LCD back light.
First, I use the code as below:

```
// Turn off monitor
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
// Turn on monitor
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) -1);
// Low power monitor
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 1);
```

But program will hang on SendMessage()
I found the [disscuss topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951658/sendmessagehwnd-broadcast-hangs) to solve hanging problem (Use: SendMessageTimeout function)

```
// Turn on monitor
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) -1, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, NULL);
// Turn off monitor
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, NULL);
// Low power monitor
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 1, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, NULL);
```

My problem is the program can not turn on monitor.

My process is: turn off monitor -> wait 10 seconds -> turn on monitor.

Monitor can be turned off, can not turn on monitor again after 10 seconds,
But I can see the monitor is on for a very short time after 10 seconds.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on Windows 8 platform, Can send a key to system to turn on LCD after turn off LCD via

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, NULL);
```

I don't know why, but it actually work well...

```
INPUT in[1];
KEYBDINPUT kb;
kb.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
in[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in[0].ki = kb;
SendInput(1, in, sizeof(in));
```

Comment: I guess the reason why is because -1 is an undocumented parameter. My guess is that they removed it so now it no longer works on Windows 10.