# Win32 API SendMessage with HWND_BROADCAST

Tags: winapi, sendmessage

I am trying to send a message using myresult=SendMessage(hWnd,...). As I understand it, SendMessage sends a Windows message to the specified target hWnd; the target's WndProc returns a long value; that value is returned by SendMessage (myresult). Am I right so far?

Ok, now if the SendMessage hWnd is HWND_BROADCAST, it is sent to all top-level windows. So which window's WndProc determines the return value?

UPDATE: 02-10-20
Just to clear up what I *hoped* to do...
My app consists of a small constellation of windows apps that need to communicate via Windows Messages. My plan was to broadcast a registered message, e.g., WM_IDENTIFYMYAPP, and identify all siblings by responses. That won't for the reason explained in the answer by Adrian Mole.

Comment: There's really only a handful or two of messages that are designed to be broadcast. Among them are `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` and `WM_DEVMODECHANGE`, i.e. messages that are intended to be notifications. I don't know what ultimately decides the return value of `SendMessage`, but have not ever found it to be useful for anything either.

Comment: The return value will be that from whatever is the last of the receiving windows to process the message and return.

Comment: Are you trying to inject code into every single process in the system that has a window? That's the only reason I can think of for using `HWND_BROADCAST` except for the notification-style messages mentioned by IInspectable (and DDE, which *no one* should be using these days).

Comment: See my updated question for my intentions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value will be that from whatever is the last of the receiving windows to process the message and return; which window this is is difficult (if not impossible) for the sending application to determine.

Generally, when you want to use `HWND_BROADCAST` to notify multiple windows (or to communicate with a window to which you don't have a handle), you should use the (asynchronous) `PostMessage` function (which returns immediately) rather than `SendMessage` (which waits for all receiving windows to process the message).

Using the (synchronous) `SendMessage` with `HWND_BROADCAST` as the target can cause many undesirable effects, as discussed [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951658/sendmessagehwnd-broadcast-hangs).  But note, there are some message that cannot be sent asynchronously (*via* `PostMessage`) - `WM_COPYDATA` is one that I know of.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Plus, there are way better alternatives than `PostMessage` for broadcasting messages (`SendNotifyMessage`, `SendMessageTimeout`, `SendMessageCallback`).

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry - I have now included the 'answer' (albeit not especially useful) from my comment to the question. But I agree with your "better alternatives!"

Comment: Ok, that does provide an answer now. I'm wondering whether this is accurate, though. I wasn't able to find any documentation on this. Do you have a link?

Comment: @IInspectable My 'information' comes from (bitter) experience - but I'm looking for a confirmatory link.

Comment: Adrian: Hmm, that's unfortunate. But I think I have a work-around to do what I want. BTW - PostXXX will not work for me.